# Ruby on Rails: filter associations based on several relations and conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

In my application I the have the models Category, Item, Property and PropertyValuation. The idea is that a category contains items, and an item has several properties. PropertyValuation purpose is to store the property value for the specific items. The models are defined as above:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :parent, :children, :items, :parent_id

  has_many :children, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :nullify
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category"

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :items, :through => :categorizations
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :property_valuations, :barcode

  has_many :property_valuations, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :properties, :through => :property_valuations 

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations

end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :value_type, :unit, :unit_id

  has_many :property_valuations, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :items, :through => :property_valuations
  has_many :property_ranges, :dependent => :destroy

  belongs_to :unit
end

class PropertyValuation < ActiveRecord::Base     
  attr_accessible :property, :item, :value, :categorization

  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Now my question, I've successfully managed to filter categories items by name by doing this:

```
@category.items.where("lower(items.name) like ?", "%#{params[:keywords].downcase}%")
```

But now I also want to filter those items depending on the associated property value. I receive the property ids and the values for each property (exact value, minimum value or maximum value), and the idea is to build the query dynamically. Given my models, how can I do this for example: I want the items whose name contains "foo", and where property with id=1 has value 2, property with id=2 has value<10, and property with id=8 has value>2 and value<5.

Answer (score 0):

You can drive the search off the `PropertyValuation` model and join it to the product and category models

```
valuations = PropertyValuation.joins(:item)
                              .where(value: 2, property_id: 1)
                              .where('lower(items.name) LIKE ?', "%#{params[keywords].downcase}%")
items      = valuations.map(&:item)
```

There a gems that make this thing a long easier, one is Ransack https://github.com/ernie/ransack

```
Item.search(name_contains:                   params[:keywords], 
            product_valuations_value_equals: 2, 
            product_valuations_property_id:  1)
```